# Angular Project Build went from 12MBs to 90MBs after upgrading from angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Build command currently using.

```
node pre-build && node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer --outputHashing=all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `angular.json` try adjusting these properties

`optimization` to `true`

`aot` to `true`

`buildOptimizer` to `true`

It will enable optimizations like `tree shaking` and get rid of unnecessary code.

Comment: I used this "--optimization",  after making the build the size was reduced.